# Error al consumir un servicio Web

Tags: web, servicio

Al consumir un servicio web me funciona localmente, pero al publicar en el servidor genera el error a continuación:

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://siscop.ica.gov.co/sciafWs/index.ica?ws=1. This could be due to
>   the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with
>   HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of
>   the security binding between the client and the server.

Comment: brother, bienvenido al sitio, coloca el código que has utilizado, porque tal y como está tu pregunta, dudo que lleguemos a solucionarla

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: El error tiene que ver con el certificado HTTPS. Sin embargo, acabo de entrar a la URL que indicas y no aparece el error (sólo está la advertencia de que el XML esta vacío). ¿Te sigue apareciendo a ti? Quizás se trató de algo temporal, mientras el certificado HTTPS entraba en vigencia.

Comment: Gracias por la información. El tema quedó solucionado asi: El servidor donde se presentaba el error era windows 2003, lo que me dijeron es que este no manejaba certificados. Se publicó en un servidor Windows 2008 y quedó solucionado.